# show div for x seconds every y minutes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS so the answer could be AngularJS or pure JS, doesn't really matter. 
Assuming it's AngularJS, I have a param called isShowDiv which will control switching between two divs according to this condition:

**Show first div every 1 minute for 10 seconds long.**

I tried using interval inside an interval, not working. My code for now looks like a big mess since I played with it a lot. So you might even ignore it (it's written in Typescript):

```
        var ppInterval1 = this.$interval(function () {
                var started = Date.now();
                var interval = this.$interval(function () {
                    // for 10 seconds
                    if (Date.now() - started > 10000) {
                        // and then pause it
                        this.$interval.cancel(ppInterval1);
                    } else {
                        this.isShowDiv= !this.isShowDiv;
                    }
                }.bind(this), 100);
        }.bind(this), 1000);
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to use an interval to invoke the function every minute. You got that already. Inside the function, you display the div and use a timeout function which will hide the div after 10 seconds again.

Comment: @HerrDerb this will make it delay for 5 seconds for each div, maybe the interval time should depend on the timeout time? Not sure i'm explaining myself correctly.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took Mario's approach and added one missing part - which will prevent the the case where you lose part of the time because of the timeout, and this is my answer (call it when you load your page):

```
    handleShow= () => {
        var i = 1;
        var extra = 0;
        var holdFor = 10;
        var showEvery = 60
        this.$interval(() => {
            i += 1;
            if (i == holdFor) {
                this.isShowDiv= false;
            }
            else if (i == showEvery+ extra) {
                i = 0;
                extra = holdFor;
                this.isShowDiv= true;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this-

```
    $interval(function() {        
        showDiv();
        $timeout(function() {
            clearDiv();
        }, 10*1000);        
    }, 60*1000);
```

You can see working here :http://plnkr.co/edit/nGKsOBmlxtU1hYFdTXeC?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified example of what that code should look like:

```
    var show;
    function execInterval() {
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                    show = true;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                            show = false;
                            clearInterval(interval);
                    }, 10000)
                    console.log(show);
            }, 1000);
    }

    execInterval();
```

Comment: it would depend on his angular code, whether it's a single instance of directive or not. For each directive this should work. However he needs to loop through all instances would depend on the rest of his code that was not added to the question.

Comment: This way, you don't need to define an interval, as it gets cleared during the first run and won't be executed anymore.

Comment: @Tatarin actually there is a problem with that. The time it takes to show the first div (the longer one) gets shortened, because it eats up from the second div timeout time on each interval. So assuming i'm defining 2 minutes for the original div, and 30 seconds for the second one, it goes like this: first time is perfect (2 minutes) then 30 seconds, then 1 minute and 30 seconds, then another 30 seconds for the second one, then 1 minute... and so on.

Comment: @DanielGreen you are correct if they share the same instance of the time variable. In order to run it in sequence you would have to structure the code to trigger the executor (the answer) in a way where it doesn't get instantiated for a single instance. 

Assuming that each instance is a directive, you would have a `$scope.showDiv` inside your directive and trigger it during some event (click, focus etc)

Comment: @Tatarin These are not on a directive. I'm not sure what to do now :)

Comment: @DanielGreen see updatred answer, wrap it inside a function and execute when needed, you can also pass in arguments to `execInterval` to accomidate more logic

Comment: @Tatarin Thanks for your patience. When you clear the interval, it won't run again, no? at least this is what is happening now. Or should I call the executeInterval function in another interval?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1 ;
  
  setInterval(function(){
    i += 1 ;
    
    if (i == 2) {
      $(".thisClass").hide() ;
    }
    else if (i == 5) {
      i = 0 ;
      $(".thisClass").show() ;
    }   
  }, 1000);
}) ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="thisClass">Will be hidden</div>
```